# Setup c# web api in vb.net Website

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have a website that was built in `VB.Net` using `ASP.NET web forms`, now I want to add a `Web Api` to it and using `c#`, is it possible? If so how to do it.

I did tried it and getting the message

> "No type was found that matches the controller named 'get' "

, so I suspect it may not be possible to mixing languages on `Web Api's`, but want to confirm.

Comment: Mixing languages within projects is not workable to my knowledge. If the classes are in different assemblies, you should be able to do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need write your csharp method in another project, and using it at your vb.net project.